# Multiple UIwebViews on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have about +3 UIwebViews, how do I code each one to go to different URLs.

Here the code from my ViewController.m file

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
    @interface ViewController ()


    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;


    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
        NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test22.php";
        NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
        [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self.view addSubview:webview];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @end
```

How can I keep the same exact code for each UIwebViews but for each one to go to different webpages?

Example: 
UIwebView1 = http://example.com/1
UIwebView2 = http://example.com/2
UIwebView1 = http://example.com/3

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices, you can create three instances of a UIWebView with a URL & request for each or you can re-use the same one and just keep re-assinging it's URL request then calling it again.

If you want to create three separate UIWebView instances you'll just do wha you have except twice more, though adding each one to your current view will just give you the last one being visible.

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test22.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url2=@"http://nextUrl";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

UIWebView *webview3=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url3=@"http://anotherNexturl";
    NSURL *nsurl3=[NSURL URLWithString:url3];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest3=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl3];
    [webview3 loadRequest:nsrequest3];
```

Or, depending on how you're switching between your web views you can just re-assign the NSURLRequest and re use the same instance of the UIWebView

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test22.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

    NSString *url2=@"http://nextUrl";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest2];

    NSString *url3=@"http://nextUrl";
    NSURL *nsurl3=[NSURL URLWithString:url3];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl3];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest3];
```

Comment: Can you provide the code, I'm a beginner at Objective-C

Comment: Updated, it's just an example you can really tweak it for how you want to use it and how you want to switch between the different URLs you want to load.

Comment: will I have to do anything to the actual UIwebViews

Comment: In one example you re use the same web view and in another you create 3 instances of a UIWebView, I don't know what your exact goals are but if you're using 3 instances you'll have to manage how they are displayed to the user if that's your goal.

Comment: I tried for a few hours last night to implement it but no matter how many times I tried, none of the codes worked :(

Comment: Update your question with the code you have now and the errors you're experiencing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84484/discussion-between-php-web-dev-101-and-thefredelement).

Comment: I created two @property IBoutlets and linked them but now both of the uiwebviews are going to the first webpage url